# Push code to a different project in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am wondering what is the best way to push code from a `CI/CD` job in Gitlab. For example,

- `project1`: where you run the `gitlab-ci`
- `project2`: where you want to push your code

Both projects are in Gitlab, and the idea is that we push code from the CI at `proejct1` to `project2`. The idea is that based on `project1` we compile and build some artifacts that later are pushed to `project2`.

One quick solution would be to use a `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN`:

```
git push https://${GITLAB_USER_LOGIN}:${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}@<your-gitlab-server>/<your-project-2-name>.git HEAD:master
```

To configure the personal token:

1. Your user profile - Settings - Access Token - "Create personal access token"
2. `Project 1` - Settings - CI/CD - Secret variables

   `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN`:

But this solution has some major **problems**:

- All members of the project will be able to see the `PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN`
- If you enable the `CI_DEBUG_TRACE` flag, the personal token will be in the output of your job

I guess it can be a temporal solution. But I am wondering what is the best solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Project mirroring seems to be the feature you are looking for :

Go to your project page
Settings->Repository Settings

There, you can configure pushong to another repository, only protected branches or everything, you choose.

I hope it'll help you.
If not, please provide more info.

Comment: the idea is not mirroring, is to build some in the CI and push it to another repository. I clarify that in the question.